# Exception while build and run flutter app

Tags: flutter

```
                           **^
```

warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':connectivity:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 1m 24s
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        85.5s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1**

Comment: `Change the ext.kotlin_version to 1.4.0`    `Change the classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0' version to 4.2.0` running the Java version above 11 make sure to use 11.

Comment: ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'  & classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2',  in app/build.gradle : compileSdkVersion 31, changed  &in  gradle-wrapper.properties changed to distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip.now it's worked for me.

Comment: Thanks @SureshBB your solution worked for me, please consider adding it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should check your gradle version with gradle version that imported packages using that .
try this
in build gradle module level :
`android/build.gradle`

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

in gradle wrapper
`android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```